# How to Parse data from Excel to property file using a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

How can I read the data from an excel file and put it inside a property file using shell scripts

Comment: Save it as a csv file or use for example `xls2csv` or `xlsx2csv`. Good luck.

Comment: Is there any particular command I should try out?